# React keydown Event Listener is being called multiple times?

Tags: reactjs

So I made this modal https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-morning-ukxp2?file=/src/components/Modal.js

Whenever you press the esc key, it is suppose to close the modal. I added a message to show each time I press esc.

But if you check the console it prints my messages in multiples of 2x each time, so after a while it will say the message like 100 times

This is the function I'm referring to

```
           function keyPress(e) {
        if (e.key === 'Escape' && showModal) {
          setShowModal(false);
          console.log('I pressed');
        }
      }

      document.addEventListener('keydown', keyPress);
```

I tried to put it into a useEffect function and add showModal as a dependency, but I couldn't get it to work properly

How would I prevent the keydown event listener from showing so many times in the console when I only want it to trigger when the modal is open and when I press the esc key once?

It seems like every time I re open the modal, it doubles the esc key message.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to handle the event listeners (add, removing) inside `useEffect` hook:

```
useEffect(() => {
  document.addEventListener("keydown", keyPress);
  return () => document.removeEventListener("keydown", keyPress);
});
```

This way, you will subscribe to `keyPress` function in every lifecycle.
To improve it further, you could wrap `keyPress` in useCallback hook (to memoize the function in new renders) and add it as a dependency:

```
  const keyPress = useCallback(
    (e) => {
      if (e.key === "Escape" && showModal) {
        setShowModal(false);
        console.log("I pressed");
      }
    },
    [setShowModal, showModal]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("keydown", keyPress);
    return () => document.removeEventListener("keydown", keyPress);
  }, [keyPress]);
```

[Modified codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-clarke-18c5e?file=/src/components/Modal.js:1395-1538)

Comment: when would I need to worry about adding an array as a dependency? or how come you didn't have to add one in this example?

Comment: You are right, that simple change would make the subscription on every lifecycle. I've added how to add your function as a dependency and memoize it to not have to create it in every re-render.

Answer (score -1):

```
 useEffect(()=>{
        document.addEventListener('keydown', someFunction); 
    }, []);
```

the empty array at the end will till react to not refresh the component once loaded