# Keydown is being pushed or outputted multiple times

Tags: reactjs

I've been trying to learn React and I know my code structure is definitely not great but for some reason this code keeps outputting my letter I touch multiple times, it's as if its multiplying every tap I do, How can I fix this? I've been stuck on it for a couple hours now atleast and I just cant seem to figure it out even when I try to google it

Main content

```
import {useState} from 'react'
 
import './app.css'
import Guess from './Guess'

const guesses = [
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  []

]

const alphabet = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"];

function App(props) {
  const count = 1
  const [keyPressed, setKeyPressed] = useState("");
  const keydownHandler = (event) => {
    const letter = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode)
    if (alphabet.includes(letter)) {
      guesses[0].push(letter)
      setKeyPressed(letter)
    }
  }
  
  document.addEventListener("keydown", keydownHandler)
  return (
    <>
    <div className='title'>
    <h1>Wordle Clone</h1>
    <p>By: Brady Smith</p>

    </div>
    <div className="container">
    {guesses.map((items, index) => {
        return (
          <ol>
            {items.map((subItems, sIndex) => {
              return <li> {subItems} </li>;
            })}
          </ol>
        );
      })}
      <Guess letter={keyPressed}/>
      <Guess />
      <Guess />
      <Guess />
      <Guess />
      <Guess />
    </div>
    
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Guess.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'


const Guess = ({letter}) => {
  return (
    <>
    <div className="guess">
      <div className="letter1">
        <h1>{letter}</h1>
      </div>
      <div className="letter2">
        <h1></h1>
      </div>
      <div className="letter3">
        <h1></h1>
      </div>
      <div className="letter4">
        <h1></h1>
      </div>
      <div className="letter5">
        <h1></h1>
      </div>
    </div>

    </>
  )
}

export default Guess
```

Comment: How do you see if it's outputted multiple times ?

Comment: Im making a map of the list that it pushes to and displaying it as a list @Kundan

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React keydown Event Listener is being called multiple times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64434545/react-keydown-event-listener-is-being-called-multiple-times)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to subscribe to `keyPress` function in every lifecycle.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  document.addEventListener("keydown", keydownHandler);
  return () => document.removeEventListener("keydown", keydownHandler);
});
```